# Unique username with parsley js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsley.js

I'm trying to use parsley's js custom validator to check for a unique email address on my form. However it's not stopping the form from submitting when I not matter what I return.

The ajax request checkEmailExists returns true or false depending on if the email exists

```
window.Parsley
  .addValidator('uniqueUsername', {
    requirementType: 'string',
    validateString: function(value, requirement) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "checkEmailExists",
        data: {username: value},
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { email: $( "#email" ).val() },
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          return data;
        }
      });
    },
    messages: {
      en: 'This email address already exists!'
    }
  });

<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-parsley-uniqueUsername data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-type="email"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The promise you are returning must fail or succeed, not succeed with `true` or `false`.

Easiest is probably to use the `remote` validator.

Not relevant, but for idempotent requests like these, you're supposed to use `GET`, not `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc said your promise must fail for succeed and also your validator name can't have capital letters or special characters so try something like this:

```
// uniqueUsername validator
window.Parsley.addValidator('uniqueusername', {
    validateString: function (value, requirement) {

        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: "users_list_ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                action: 'checkUserExists',
                username: value
            }
        });

        return xhr.then(function (data) {
            console.log((data.isUnique == 0));

            if (data.isUnique == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return $.Deferred().reject();
            }
        });
    },
    messages: {
        en: 'Username already exists!',
        ar: 'إسم المستخدم موجود مسبقا'
    },
    priority: 32
});
```

Comment: sir i need to know new update of parsley js also will work with this? i am stuck on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999599/parsley-2-8-1-unique-username-validation-with-php could look at this? thank you

Comment: Yes it should work with Parsley new version. Just make sure that your .php page is being called correctly and is not returning any irrelevant HTTP error.