# Parsley (2.8.1) unique username validation with php

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-4, parsley.js

I read all the documentation of the Parsley Js web site. But i not get enough understand how to set custom validation depend on AJAX response.

I need to validate a username and check if it is already exist in the database if it is yes and show the error when hit the submit button.

I look around here and try to find any question regarding to this i could not fine that only i got how ajax code should place to validate that forms. I need to know how the PHP file look likes. That why i post that question

I am using parsley js new version. Here is my code look like

```
<form class="forms-sample" id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputUsername1">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername1" 
             name="username" placeholder="Username" required data-parsley-username>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-light">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

and i am using Bootstrap 4 for CSS. My Parsley js script like this

```
        <script>
     window.ParsleyValidator
            .addValidator('username', function (value, requirement) {
                var response = false;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "username.php",
                    data: {username: value},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        response = true;
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        response = false;
                    }
                });
                return response;
            }, 32)
            .addMessage('en', 'username', 'The username already exists.');

    $("#form").parsley({
    errorClass: 'is-invalid',
    successClass: 'is-valid',
    errorsWrapper: '<span class="invalid-feedback"></span>',
    errorTemplate: '<span></span>',
    trigger: 'change'

});
</script>
```

I cannot imaging how i create PHP file to write query and what i want to echo from  that PHP.

Could you please tell me anything need to be change here and can you guide me to build that PHP file to complete this task. And i need to know this JS will work or not. Thank you.

After i added a php file. that is something like this

```
<?php 
        include("include/connection.php");
    ?>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['username'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName = '%$username'";
            $q = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) { 
                echo json_encode("error");
            }else { 
                echo json_encode("success");
            } 
        }
    ?>
```

but i got default error message for every time that was "The username already exists." Can anybody know what is the error in here?

Comment: If you do not know how to do a sql query using a post variable then perhaps change from php to a language you're more comfortable with? Jquery runs the success/error functions based on the http status code of the request, so if you return 200 OK (default) it will go into the success callback, if you return anything else it will enter the error callback

Comment: No i know how to query with the database table, i need to know what want to return from the php file

Comment: If you can send me the repo, I might be able to find a answer. PM

Comment: i will send it to you brother :)

Comment: Use chrome developer tools to check if your username.php page is being called correctly and is not returning any syntax error.

Comment: it is perfectly fine. i check it and checked it some others. they also not found the solution. problem in parsley js syntax i think so. i haven't useful documentation to solve this :(

Answer (score 0):

in username.php you're going to run a basic select query on the username you pass, then return the data based on whether it finds a result or not.

The following should be pretty close.

PHP

```
if ($user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user_table_name` WHERE `username_field_name` = $_POST['username']"))) {
    print(json_encode(['status'] => 'user_exists']))

} else {
    print(json_encode(['status'] => 'user_available']))
}
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: "username.php",
    data: {username: value},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if( data.status === 'user_available ) {
        //continue your code
        } else {
        //alert user that the name is unavailable
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir this ajax part will suited for parsley js ajax method also?

Comment: in parsley js use success: function(data) {
                            response = true;
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            response = false;
                        }
                    });
                    return response;  this code line. can i move on to this?

Comment: The Parsley part happens before the AJAX call from what I can tell, it shouldn't affect it.

Comment: mmm still im not figure out that problem sir. any way thank for your effort